# Installing MSSQL server express using docker with full text search support

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-express

I am using mssql express for ubuntu on docker. I just found that it does not support full text search. I believe the mssql express supports this, but found no way to enable this feature.

Here is the image I'm using.

> image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu

I am passing express edition as environment as MSSQL_PID: "Express".

How can I have full text search installed on the same image ?

Comment: *"I just found that it does not support full text search."* Full-Text searches are available on all editions of versions of SQL Server 2017; including those on Linux.

Comment: But when using docker image, this feature is not installed? How do we install it?

Comment: The default image does not have it enabled, no. You would need to amend the command line parameters to enable Full text Searching and then build your own image.

Comment: Where is MS on this 3 years later so disappointing

Answer (score 4):

Default mssql docker image does not support fts, i.e. full text search, therefore we need to create the custom sql image.

Here is the dockerfile for the same... based on the microsoft repo at
https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools/Dockerfile

```
# Maintainers: Microsoft Corporation (twright-msft on GitHub)
# GitRepo: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker

# Base OS layer: Latest Ubuntu LTS
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install prerequistes since it is needed to get repo config for SQL server
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq curl apt-transport-https && \
    # Get official Microsoft repository configuration
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    # Install SQL Server from apt
    apt-get install -y mssql-server && \
    # Install optional packages
    apt-get install -y mssql-server-ha && \
    apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts && \
    # Cleanup the Dockerfile
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

# Run SQL Server process
CMD /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous responses focus on the LINUX container of MSSQL. This is for windows, copy this PS into the image using docker file and run it:

```
    $global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    Import-Module Sbs;

    # Download SQL Server ISO
    SbsDownloadFile -Url "https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/d/38de7036-2433-4207-8eae-06e247e17b25/SQLServer2022-x64-ENU-Dev.iso" -Path "C:\SQLServer2022-x64-ENU-Dev.iso";

    # Create a directory to extract the ISO contents
    New-Item -Path C:\SQLServerISO -ItemType Directory;

    # Use 7z to extract the ISO contents
    7z x C:\SQLServer2022-x64-ENU-Dev.iso -oC:\SQLServerISO;

    # Define directory paths
    $systemDbDir = 'C:\SQLSystemDB\Data';
    $systemDbLogDir = 'C:\SQLSystemDB\Log';
    $userDbDir = 'C:\SQLUserDB\Data';
    $userDbLogDir = 'C:\SQLUserDB\Log';
    $backupDir = 'C:\SQLBackup';
    $installDir = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server';

    # Ensure all required directories exist
    New-Item -Path $systemDbDir, $systemDbLogDir, $userDbDir, $userDbLogDir, $backupDir, $installDir -ItemType Directory -Force;

    # Install SQL Server from the extracted files
    $process = Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\SQLServerISO\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/Q",
        "/ACTION=install",
        "/SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE",
        "/INSTANCEID=MSSQLSERVER",
        "/INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER",
        "/FEATURES=SqlEngine,FullText",
        "/INSTALLSQLDATADIR=`"$installDir`"",
        "/SQLUSERDBDIR=`"$userDbDir`"",
        "/SQLUSERDBLOGDIR=`"$userDbLogDir`"",
        "/SQLTEMPDBDIR=`"$systemDbDir`"",
        "/SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR=`"$systemDbLogDir`"",
        "/SQLBACKUPDIR=`"$backupDir`"",
        "/UpdateEnabled=0",
        "/TCPENABLED=1", 
        "/NPENABLED=0",
        "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS",
        "/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=ContainerAdministrator" -PassThru;

    # Check the exit code
    if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Error "SQL Server installation failed with exit code $($process.ExitCode)."
        exit $process.ExitCode
    }

    # Cleanup: Remove the ISO and extracted files
    Remove-Item -Path C:\SQLServer2022-x64-ENU-Dev.iso -Force; `
    Remove-Item -Path C:\SQLServerISO -Recurse -Force;
```

Link to the repo that contains the docker files for the complete setup:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/tree/master/sqlserver2022base